# How to rename duplicates in list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need a list of unique values. But it could be, the values exists twice or more in the list. 
If this occurs I must rename the value but the renamed value also could be in the list.

It is possible to rename the values using a LINQ query so i don't need a sub-query?

example 1:
**before**:
"one", "one", "two", "two", "three"
**after**:
"one", "one_", "two", "two_", "three"

example 2:
**before**:
"one", "one", "one_"
**after**:
"one", "one_", "one__"

The 3rd "one" has 2 underscores because the 2nd "one" was renamed to "one_".

Thanks a lot for an idea...

Comment: LINQ is not great for modifying collections, but for querying them. I'd go with Alxandr's suggestion.

Comment: @Jens: this does not ask for modification of TSource, just querying derived items. Agree with the suggestion though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think this should be done with simply a linq-query. I'd use a HashSet and create a function if I was you. Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<String> GetUnique(IEnumerable<String> list) {
    HashSet<String> itms = new HashSet<String>();
    foreach(string itm in list) {
         string itr = itm;
         while(itms.Contains(itr)) {
             itr = itr + "_";
         }
         itms.Add(itr);
         yield return itr;
    }
}
```

#### [Edit]

This could be made into an extension-method though, so you could call it like this: `myList.GetUnique();` (or something like that)

#### [Edit 2]

Fixed bug with iterator-variable being changed.

Comment: Was about to post something like this!  My only suggestions would be to make this an extension method so it's a bit easier to call, and to use a ``StringBuilder`` when you're building up the candidate string to be inserted to avoid a bunch of inefficient string concatenations.

Comment: @Alxandr: Darn, that's twice I've been beaten to the punch while typing my own answer :-)

Comment: I thought about using a StringBuilder, but then I thought that normally you'd probably only use lists witch adds 1 or 2 "_" at the end; In that case I thought that the gain of using a StringBuilder over the cost of calling ToString in the while-loop... Well, I just thought it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: @Alxandr: Agreed, since you need the string each time for the lookup, the concat (+) is more efficient.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Wait, what? You mean that if I do `string a = "a"; string b = "b"; string c = a + b;` C# (behind the scenes) creates a StringBuilder for concatenation? Isn't that wasted memory and stuff?

Comment: Cannot assign to 'itm' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: @Alxandr: I stand corrected. `StringBuilder` only gets created when you're appending more than four strings together.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Uniquifier(this IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

    var unique = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach(var item in values)
    {
        var newItem = item;

        while(unique.Contains(newItem))
        {
            newItem += '_';
        }

        unique.Add(newItem);

        yield return newItem;
    }
}
```

This will take any sequence of string, and create a HashSet - very fast, O(1) - of the values.  If the value already exists, it appends a '_' and tries again.  Once it has one unique, returns it.

Comment: This was the FIRST answer to actually compile and work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using an extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Uniquify(this IEnumerable<string> enumerable, string suffix)
    {
        HashSet<string> prevItems = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach(var item in enumerable)
        {
            var temp = item;
            while(prevItems.Contains(temp))
            {
                temp += suffix;
            }
            prevItems.Add(temp);
            yield return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var test1 = new[] {"one","one","two","two","three"};
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",test1.Uniquify("_")));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=BYFVK87508

**Edit:** Using the while loop now supports all cases previously unsupported as per comments below.

Comment: You should switch the list with a HashSet. Much faster.

Comment: Wrong algorithm. Test with `"one", "one_", "one"`

Comment: Doesn't work if there is more than one occurrence of the same string value.