# Make a list containing distinct list items from dataset containing duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, list, comparison, string-comparison

I'm really stuck, and being as many of you guys that post solutions on here are by and large brilliant (IMHO), I figured I'd see what the best of you could make of this problem.

Some background

I'm trying to create a list that must contain only distinct items in a specific sequence.
(it's a primary key and thus must be distinct (I didn't make it a primary key, but I have to work with what I'm given, you know how it goes).

For ease of understanding this requirement, think of creating a distinct list of recipe steps from a book of recipes.  My problem is that the "cooks" of these "recipes" often change the order in which they create their masterpieces.

For instance:

### Recipe 1

- Whisk eggs using fork
- Melt margarine in a skillet
- Pour in the eggs
- stir constantly
- Plate
- Add salt and pepper as desired

### Recipe 2

- Break eggs into bowl
- Whisk eggs using fork
- Melt margarine in a skillet over low heat
- Pour in the eggs
- stir constantly
- Plate
- Serve
- Add salt and pepper as desired

### Recipe 3

- Whisk eggs using fork
- Add salt and pepper as desired
- Melt margarine in a skillet over low heat
- Pour in the eggs
- stir constantly
- Plate

As you can tell "Add salt and pepper..." can't be number 2 in Recipe 3 and still be in the correct sequence in Recipes 1 and 2.

I think if I can ID the "offending" list item and add a period to the end of it, thus making it unique, this would work as a solution.

How do I do this in C# given a dataset (gotten by a SQL query) with duplicates in the correct sequence and placed into a List of type string? LINQ is not a requirement here, but I'm not afraid to use it if it provides a solution.

Specifically code (or psedo-code) that:

- IDs the list item that needs to be duplicated and modified.
- Determine WHERE in the newly created large list (assuming) is the newly modified list item to be placed.

If Your 1st question is going to be "show me your work", please be advised that I've done quite a bit of work on this, and the code is generally long.
I am happy to work from either pseudo-code or try your code with my dataset.
I'm also happy reading other solutions that may be pertinent.

Thanks, I look forward to seeing your solutions.

--edit:  I'm starting to get the impression people don't like it if you don't post code.
So here it goes (I said above it was long).  The code works but it doesn't solve the problem.  It returns a distinct list in order with no duplicates.
(If the formatting below is bad please forgive)

```
    public void GetNewRecipeItemsFromDB(string RequestedRecipeName)
    {
        string connString = string.Empty;
        string strGetRecipeElements_Sql = "SQL that returns the dataset";
        string connString = GetConnectionString();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strGetRecipeElements_Sql;
            SqlDataReader reader = null;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strGetRecipeElements_Sql, conn);
                DataSet RecipeItems = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(RecipeItems, "RecipeItems");
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<string> RecipeItemList = new List<string>();

                //Create an array with existing RecipeItems

                int readerCount = 0;


                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    RecipeItems GSI = new RecipeItems();
                    GSI.RecipeItem = reader[0].ToString();
                    GSI.Sequence = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1].ToString());
                    GSI.Rank = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2].ToString());


                    RecipeItemList.Add(GSI.RecipeItem.ToString());
                    readerCount++;

                }
                string[] CurrentRecipeItemArray = new string[readerCount];
                string[] UpdatedRecipeItemArray = new string[readerCount];

                //RecipeItemList.Sort();
                label1.Text = "";
                textBox1.Text = "";
                CurrentRecipeItemArray = RecipeItemList.ToArray();

                for (int y = CurrentRecipeItemArray.Length - 1; y >= 0; y--)
                {


                    textBoxDBOrginal.Text += CurrentRecipeItemArray[y].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                }

                string[] lines = textBoxDBOrginal.Text.ToString().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                List<string> UniqueRecipeItemsInvertedList = new List<string>();
                if (lines.Length > 0)
                {
                    //OK it's not null lets look at it.
                    int lineCount = lines.Length;
                    string NewCompare = string.Empty;

                    for (int z = 0; z < lineCount; z++)

                    {
                        NewCompare = lines[z];
                        if (!UniqueRecipeItemsInvertedList.Contains(NewCompare))
                        {
                            UniqueRecipeItemsInvertedList.Add(NewCompare);

                        }
                    }
                }
                UniqueRecipeItemsInvertedList.Reverse();

                foreach (string s in UniqueRecipeItemsInvertedList)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                    {

                        listBox7.Items.Add(s.ToString());

                    }
                }


            }


            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Errors.ToString());

            }
            conn.Close();


        }



    }
```

Comment: Why the downgrades?  If you're going to downgrade it you should at least say why so I know better next time.

Comment: Guess this fell off the radar.  Disappointing.

Comment: I found this [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449999/whats-the-most-efficient-way-of-generating-all-possible-combinations-of-skyrim/8451384#8451384  DavidB [link] http://stackoverflow.com/users/8155/david-b did a great job (IMHO) in his C# Example.  This is close if I can wrap my head around applying this solution to my problem.  :)

Comment: This blog post also pertains http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct.aspx

Comment: OK, looks like the C# keyword Dictionary might hold the key (pardon the pun) here http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary.

Comment: I think I might be on to it. http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Duplicates.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was already on this site.
[How to rename duplicates in list using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163467/how-to-rename-duplicates-in-list-using-linq)

Code is:

```
      IEnumerable<String> GetUnique(IEnumerable<String> list)
    {
        HashSet<String> itms = new HashSet<String>();
        foreach(string itm in list)
        {
            string itr = itm;
            while(itms.Contains(itr))
            {
                itr = itr + "_";
            }
            itms.Add(itr);
            yield return itr;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Dictionary won't allow for duplicate entries (it throws an ArgumentException was unhandled exception), thus handling the "heavy lifting" of ensuring uniqueness and sequence order (still testing that one).  I think I'm using GSI.Sequence wrong because there could be multiple sequences for receipe items. (This is NOT the answer, but a place I could put code.  I hope I did it right)   Hat tip to http://williablog.net/williablog/post/2011/08/30/Generic-AddOrUpdate-Extension-for-IDictionary.aspx

```
      while(reader.Read())
     {
                    RecipeItems GSI = new RecipeItems();
                    GSI.RecipeItem = reader[0].ToString();
                    GSI.Sequence = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1].ToString());
                    GSI.RecipeName = reader[2].ToString();
                    GSI.MaxSequence = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3].ToString());



                    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(GSI.RecipeItem))
                    {
                          dictionary.[GSI.RecipeItem] = GSI.Sequence);
                    }
                    else
                    {    
                        dictionary.Add(GSI.RecipeItem, GSI.Sequence);
                    }




    }
```

I think the final answer here ended up being something that I didn't necessarily foresee or desire. With approximately 94 unique items, you will end up with a list of about 428 unique recipe items over the course of 20 recipes.  This would give me a list where I could have the appropriate recipe item in the right sequence.  I still think my logic on this one is BAD, but it makes sense when you figure you have a couple of recipe items per recipe out of order and must be duplicated and than you multiply that times the number of recipes.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion that although this can be done, and I got close, I just don't have the skills/knowledge to pull it off.

It amounts to:

1. Cycle through total number of recipes and place recipe name in a list
2. For each recipe name in list of recipes Get Recipe Steps And Sequence From DB and place in a sorted list (and this is an iffy bit).
3. At this point you have all the data you need if you just wanted the distinct items.         ListName.Distinct()
4. Cycling through the SortedList to see if the key/value exists in the proper sequence continues to be my death knell.  I kept running into key already exists / Key doesn't exists exceptions.  If I can crack this nut, I'll have solved the problem.

I learned quite a bit about list<>, sortedList<> and List and the power of having your own class(es) and methods.  For example:  RecipeInfo.RecipeItemsList makes life so much easier.

I still haven't figured out why no one here wanted to touch this or why it was down graded.  This experience will likely result in me hesitating before posting another question to stackoverflow.com.